# Add click event handling to morph

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, morphic

I want to handle mouse click on a morph in an easy way. Can I do something like:

```
'hello' asMorph
  onClick: [ :e | "baboom" ];
  openInHand
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
StringMorph subclass: #ClickMorph
    instanceVariableNames: 'action'
    classVariableNames: ''
    category: 'MyMorph'

handlesMouseDown: evt
    ^true

mouseDown: evt
    evt hand waitForClicksOrDrag: self event: evt

mouseUp: evt
    action value

action
    ^ action

action: anObject
    action := anObject
```

You can call that as

```
(ClickMorph contents: 'Click me') 
    action: [Transcript open];
    openInWorld
```

The essentials are of course to have a block and to make sure you can react to a click.

Comment: I was wandering if it's possible to do something like that with the original one, but you answered even more :) Thank you